# How to Debug Nodejs 6.x in visual code more efficiently

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am using windows
Latest Visual Code 1.59
I have used nvm to install nodejs 6.X and several current versions
I can run a node application using 6.X and use console.log to validate life is good.

I can debug using the information called out [Here](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27). It works, but it is a little clunky.

I was curious if there is a slightly more efficient way to solve this problem. I cannot change the node version to 8 or greater which appears to be more integrated with vs code. All of the associated tools like Chrome are changing, so it is difficult to match things up going back to Node 6

Comment: 6.x reached end of life over two years ago. It doesn't get security fixes any longer. I **strongly** recommend you fix whatever is stopping you switching to a supported version of Node.js instead of trying to get 6.x to work. You should be using **at least** 12.x.

Comment: I appreciate the update to the latest. This is an internal tool (ie you are on a specific subnet in a corporate network to touch it) with an 8 to 12 month sunset and the powers that be did not want to spend time fixing the coupling issues preventing the move. We all have our brown grass at times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad luck on my Visual Code selection. If I had been using 1.59, the launch.config was accurate. However in 1.60, they changed the support for the legacy node debuggers. You need to change the launch.json file "type": "legacy-node"

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "legacy-node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.js",
                       

    }
]
```

}

details here https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60